# How to turn a website into an iOS app?

Tags: ios, mobile

I have developed a website, tailored from the ground up, and are now thinking of turning it into an iOS app - to begin with.
The site is a responsive website programmed with html5, css3, javascript, xml, json, php and mysql.

Here's the url: http://drinksta.thomaskile.me (it's norwegian language)

The site will have a profile service, and the app should be synchronized with that profile, and share the same mysql database as the website.

When googling how to turn websites into an app, I get to sites where businesses wants to do the job for me. I would like to know how I can do it by my self. I wasn't sure where to post and ask this. But i have xCode on my mac, and have learned that this program is used to build apps, but with that approach, I would have to build the app from ground up?

This might not be a good question, but didn't know where to put it...

Comment: WebViews as 'Applications' are generally frowned upon. You should consider writing a more native implementation tailored for iOS devices.

Comment: so, would studying xcode be the way to go then? Trying to recreate what I have created on the website?

Comment: Step back and think about why you want an app. What benefit would your users have with a native iOS app over simply accessing the app in their favorite web browser on their iOS device?

Comment: it's a good question. Easier and faster access. Offline database access. Geolocation service (might be available on the site for that matter). Other than that - possible income opportunities...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to develop it using native iOS from the ground up.

However, if the back-end functionality is detached form the current website, like a REST/JSON style, it can make the native work easier.

By the way, you can also look up on [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) for a cross platform 'Almost Native' feel but it will have to be built from scratch anyway and sometimes 'Almost' doesn't cut it.

Comment: the backend is not currently part of the website, but is of course sharing the same database...  
Thanks for suggesting Ionic. I'm looking into it.